# pretty printer with Python?

Tags: python, pretty-print

I have a list of labels, and data as follows.

```
['id', 'Version', 'chip_name', 'xversion', 'device', 'opt_param', 'place_effort']
[1, 1.0, u'virtex2', u'xilinx11.5', u'xc5vlx50', u'Speed', u'High']
```

I need to print them into console. And for this, I'm iterating over the list, and print out each element with a tab ('\t').

But, unfortunately, the result is not so pretty.

```
number of data 1 and number of column 7
id      Version     chip_name       xversion        device      opt_param       place_effort        
1       1.0     virtex2     xilinx11.5      xc5vlx50        Speed       High
```

The string length of label and data is quite variable, and it's not aligned well.

Is there any  solution to this problem with Python?

### ADDED

Hepled by Mike DeSimone's answer, I could make the pretty printer that I can use for my purposes. The valueResults are a list of duple.

```
    labels = queryResult.names
    valueResults = queryResult.result

    # get the maximum width
    allData = valueResults
    allData.insert(0,labels)
    transpose = zip(*valueResults) # remove the sequence as a parameter
    #print transpose
    for value in transpose:
        # value is integer/float/unicode/str, so make it length of str
        newValue = [len(str(i)) for i in value]
        columnWidth = max(newValue)
        columnWidths.append(columnWidth)
        dividers.append('-' * columnWidth)
        dblDividers.append('=' * columnWidth)
        label = value[0]
        paddedLabels.append(label.center(columnWidth))

    paddedString = ""

    for values in valueResults[1:]:
        paddedValue = []
        for i, value in enumerate(values):
            svalue = str(value)
            columnWidth = columnWidths[i]
            paddedValue.append(svalue.center(columnWidth))
        paddedString += '| ' + ' | '.join(paddedValue) + ' |' + '\n'

    string += '+-' + '-+-'.join(dividers) + '-+' + '\n'
    string += '| ' + ' | '.join(paddedLabels) + ' |' + '\n'
    string += '+=' + '=+='.join(dblDividers) + '=+' + '\n'
    string += paddedString
    string += '+-' + '-+-'.join(dividers) + '-+' + '\n'
```

And this is the result.

```
+----+---------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+
| id | Version | chip_name |  xversion  |  device  | opt_param | place_effort |
+====+=========+===========+============+==========+===========+==============+
| 1  |   1.0   |  virtex2  | xilinx11.5 | xc5vlx50 |   Speed   |     High     |
| 2  |   1.0   |  virtex2  | xilinx11.5 | xc5vlx50 |   Speed   |     High     |
+----+---------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
labels = ['id', 'Version', 'chip_name', 'xversion', 'device', 'opt_param', 
    'place_effort']
values = [1, 1.0, u'virtex2', u'xilinx11.5', u'xc5vlx50', u'Speed', u'High']

paddedLabels = []
paddedValues = []

for label, value in zip(labels, values):
    value = str(value)
    columnWidth = max(len(label), len(value))
    paddedLabels.append(label.center(columnWidth))
    paddedValues.append(value.center(columnWidth))

print ' '.join(paddedLabels)
print ' '.join(paddedValues)
```

Output:

```
id Version chip_name  xversion   device  opt_param place_effort
1    1.0    virtex2  xilinx11.5 xc5vlx50   Speed       High
```

If you want to get fancy, make it [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html)-ready:

```
labels = ['id', 'Version', 'chip_name', 'xversion', 'device', 'opt_param', 
    'place_effort']
values = [1, 1.0, u'virtex2', u'xilinx11.5', u'xc5vlx50', u'Speed', u'High']

paddedLabels = []
paddedValues = []
dividers = []
dblDividers = []

for label, value in zip(labels, values):
    value = str(value)
    columnWidth = max(len(label), len(value))
    paddedLabels.append(label.center(columnWidth))
    paddedValues.append(value.center(columnWidth))
    dividers.append('-' * columnWidth)
    dblDividers.append('=' * columnWidth)

print '+-' + '-+-'.join(dividers) + '-+'
print '| ' + ' | '.join(paddedLabels) + ' |'
print '+=' + '=+='.join(dblDividers) + '=+'
print '| ' + ' | '.join(paddedValues) + ' |'
print '+-' + '-+-'.join(dividers) + '-+'
```

Output:

```
+----+---------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+
| id | Version | chip_name |  xversion  |  device  | opt_param | place_effort |
+====+=========+===========+============+==========+===========+==============+
| 1  |   1.0   |  virtex2  | xilinx11.5 | xc5vlx50 |   Speed   |     High     |
+----+---------+-----------+------------+----------+-----------+--------------+
```

Comment: This will result in uneven column widths if the values are of different lengths. You'll need to find the maximum of *all* values (and the header label) to know how wide to make each column.

Comment: I was assuming that prosseek would figure that much out.  My answer is focused on the use of `zip`, `str.center`, and `str.join`.

Answer (score 4):

Use ljust to stuff the contents before they are printed out.

```
import sys

def maxwidth(table, index):
    """Get the maximum width of the given column index"""
    return max([len(str(row[index])) for row in table])

def pprint_table(table):
    colpad = []

    for i in range(len(table[0])):
        colpad.append(maxwidth(table, i))

    for row in table:
        print str(row[0]).ljust(colpad[0] + 1),
        for i in range(1, len(row)):
            col = str(row[i]).rjust(colpad[i] + 2)
            print "", col,
        print ""

a = ['id', 'Version', 'chip_name', 'xversion', 'device', 'opt_param', 'place_effort']
b = [1, 1.0, u'virtex2', u'xilinx11.5', u'xc5vlx50', u'Speed', u'High']

# Put it in the table

c = [a, b]

pprint_table(c)
```

output:

```
id     Version    chip_name      xversion      device    opt_param    place_effort 
1          1.0      virtex2    xilinx11.5    xc5vlx50        Speed            High
```

Comment: A small fix for allow pprint_table work with python2/3:
`def pprint_table(table):
    colpad = []
    side_spaces=3

    for i in range(len(table[0])):
        colpad.append(maxwidth(table, i))

    for row in table:
        sys.stdout.write(str(row[0]).ljust(colpad[0] + 1))
        for i in range(1, len(row)):
            col = str(row[i]).rjust(colpad[i] + side_spaces)
            sys.stdout.write(str(''+  col))
        print ('')`

Answer (score 3):

you could try this

```
>>> table = {'Sjoerd': 4127, 'Jack': 4098, 'Dcab': 7678}
>>> for name, phone in table.items():
...     print '{0:10} ==> {1:10d}'.format(name, phone)
...
Jack       ==>       4098
Dcab       ==>       7678
Sjoerd     ==>       4127
```

from http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html

The integer after the `:`  is the padding.

or better yet

```
>>> table = {'Sjoerd': 4127, 'Jack': 4098, 'Dcab': 8637678}
>>> print ('Jack: {0[Jack]:d}; Sjoerd: {0[Sjoerd]:d}; '
...        'Dcab: {0[Dcab]:d}'.format(table))
Jack: 4098; Sjoerd: 4127; Dcab: 8637678
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ready solution: : [prettytable A simple Python library for easily displaying tabular data in a visually appealing ASCII table format](http://code.google.com/p/prettytable/)

Other solutions, see my similar questions other answers: [How to extend pretty print module to tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319540/how-to-extend-pretty-print-module-to-tables)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is not to use tab at all, and uses spaces to adjust column width, also no need of manually padding, as '%Ns' string formatting comes handy e.g.

```
header = ['id', 'Version', 'chip_name', 'xversion', 'device', 'opt_param', 'place_effort']
rows = [[1, 1.0, u'virtex2', u'xilinx11.5', u'xc5vlx50', u'Speed', u'High']]

def print_row(row):
    column_width=12
    format_str = ("%-"+str(column_width)+"s")*len(row)
    print format_str%tuple(row)

print_row(header)
for row in rows:
    print_row(row)
```

**Output:**

```
id          Version     chip_name   xversion    device      opt_param   place_effort
1           1.0         virtex2     xilinx11.5  xc5vlx50    Speed       High
```

Answer (score 0):

For a quick solution, If ln is the list containing all these lists,

```
for l in ln:
    print "\t".join([str(x).ljust(10) for x in l])
```

will print columns seperated by tab and left-justified. Increase the value inside ljust if it isn't pretty yet.